# Join two DataTable one from excel data and other from text file to display it in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show data in datagridview in c# using from two source one from excel sheet and other from text file .I want to join these data source .For example if I get columns from Excel sheet excel1 excel2 AND Txt1 Txt2 from text file .Then I want to show result like excel1 excel2 Txt1 Txt2 in data grid view.
 Current i can show data from excel file using below code.

```
private void button_cars_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String name = "Car List";
    String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "c:\\Vehicle_List.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select CARID, BRAND, MODEL, FUEL, CC, YEAR From [" + name + "$]", con);
    con.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(data);
    dataGridViewMain.DataSource = data;
}
```

Comment: What is the columns in txt1 ,txtw and excel2 ?

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection.  sanitize your inputs, and parameterize your queries.  just sayin...

Comment: Where is the part where you load you text file? Parse that file and add rows to the DataTable

Comment: This post should be deleted as there are very few chances other users will benefit inf finding solutions to **their** problems from here.

Answer (score 0):

I handle this situation like this

```
public DataTable mergeSheetAndTextFile()
        {
            String name = "Sheet1";
            String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                            "D:\\YOURPATH\\List.xlsx" +
                            ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select col1,col2 From [" + name + "$]", con);
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);

            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
             data.Columns.Add("Txt1Col", typeof(System.String));
            string[] txtFileLines= File.ReadAllLines("c://YOURPATH//test.txt");
           int count=0;
             foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
            {
                 if(count<txtFileLines.Length){
                    row["Txt1Col"]=txtFileLines[count]
                    count++;`enter code here`
                 }
            }
}
```